# How to define/send derived metrics in addition to built-in Aerospike metrics

Tags: metrics, aerospike

I'm trying to ship Aerospike metrics to another node using some available methods, e.g., collectd.

For example, among the Aerospike monitoring metrics, given two fields: say X and Y, how can I define and send a derived metric like Z = X+Y or X/Y?

We could calculate it on the receiver side but it degrades the performance of our application overall. Will appreciate your guidance in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done within the Aerospike collectd plugin, as the metrics are more or less shipped immediately once they are read. There's no variable that saves the metrics that have been shipped.

If you can use the Graphite plugin, it keeps track of all gathered metrics then sends once at the very end. You can add another stanza for your calculated metrics right before [nmsg line.](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-graphite/blob/develop/asgraphite.py#L865) You'll have to search through the msg[] array for your source metrics.

The Nagios plugin is a very different method. It's a single metric pull, so a wrapper script would be needed to run the plugin for each operand, and run the calculation in the wrapper.

Or you can supplement existing plugins with your own script(s) just for derived metrics. All of our monitoring plugins utilize the [Aerospike Info Protocol](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info) and you can use `asinfo` to gather metrics for your operands similar to the previous Nagios method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your insights on my issue. What if I'd like to use carbon collectd plugin instead of network plugin for shipping the metrics? Can I implement it similarly to the graphite plugin way you mentioned? I'll also consider the other ways you suggested.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with carbon collectd plugin, but on the surface it looks like it's still a network shipper that ships directly to Graphite's backend of Carbon, instead of going through Graphite's frontend.

When I mentioned plugins previously, I meant the various Aerospike monitoring plugins.

Comment: Seems you could use [aggregation-rules.conf](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf) to derive new metrics from existing metrics.